# Find the max absolute value of values in a dict using TCL

Tags: list, sorting, tcl

I have a list eg MyList

```
 set MyList [ list 508 1.648E-01 509 1.670E-01 510 1.701E-01 511 1.740E-01 512 1.784E-01 ]
```

How can I extract the **Key / Value**  pair where: The absolute value of the values is max within the list ?? (What a sentence...)

In this case 512 1.784E-01

I would create a foreach loop  and save the key value whenever the abs(Value) is greater than the previous pair. Is there a method without a loop? Im on tcl 8.5 so the "lsort  -stride" trick is out of reach.

Comment: When I have key/value pairs, I usually store them in pairs, in a list, like `[list {key1 value1} {key2 value2} ...]`, and that way, I can use `lsort -index 1 $MyList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a new list containing key/value *sublists*

```
foreach {k v} $MyList {lappend newlist [list $k $v]}
```

Then use

```
lassign [lindex [lsort -real -index 1 $newlist] end] max_key max_val
```

Comment: or with 8.6, you could use `lsort -stride 2`

Answer (score 2):

The straight-forward way is to use `dict for` to do a classic iterate-over-collection with the dictionary.

```
set maxVal -Inf
dict for {k v} $MyList {
    if {$v > $maxVal} {
        set maxKey $k
        set maxVal $v
    }
}
```

The `-Inf`? A numeric value smaller than every other value. (IEEE arithmetic is great sometimes.)

Comment: I've no idea if this will be faster than Glenn's answer. For short collections of data, maybe not. Someone ought to test. But for large dictionaries, this should win as it is a simple O(N) scan instead of a O(N) scan followed by a O(NlogN) sort…